# How to insert a variable into an html string making sure it isn't being inserted into an element using c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to insert a specific variable into an HTML string at a specific index (this could always change as could the HTML string).

Problem I'm getting is that some times the index is within an html element.

What would be the best way to get around this?

```
public static string AppendStringWithReadMoreFlag(string htmlString, int readMoreCount)
{
    string readMoreFlag = "<!--pagebreak-->";
    var html = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    html.LoadHtml(htmlString);
    int length = html.DocumentNode.InnerText.Length;

    if (length > readMoreCount)
    {
        // check if index is in a an html element
        // perhaps check if > is before < else move to the index after > ?
        htmlString = htmlString.Insert(readMoreCount, readMoreFlag);
    }

    return htmlString;
}
```

Comment: Is readMoreCount what you are referring to as index?

Comment: Yes, so as long as the readmorecount is higher than the length then I want to add the flag into the html string

Comment: It's like "parse and edit html" question that was asked many many times before. With such complex cases I prefer you to use some parsing and edit html library.

Comment: Your code says if the length is greater than readMoreCount and not what you are saying in your comment.  Thought I would point that out.

Comment: Sorry, yes it is meant to work it out length > readMoreCount

Answer (score 1):

You can try to find first `<` or `>` after place you want to insert, so you'll know if you are inserting inside an element or not, then you can use that to correct index. see below code:

```
// get indexes of < and > after place you want to insert
var idx1 = html.DocumentNode.InnerText.IndexOf('<', readMoreCount + 1);
var idx2 = html.DocumentNode.InnerText.IndexOf('>', readMoreCount + 1);
// determine which is first: one that closes element, or one that open
if(idx2 < idx1)
  // In that case we wil put text right after element is closed with ">"
  readMoreCount = idx2 + 1;
```

Comment: Ah yes, that's more like what I was thinking (and failing) to do. Still dumping the flag inside an element but closer. Thank you.

 `<a href=\"/{localLink:test<!--pagebreak-->235e8d2b}\" title=\"testHotel\">`